# Is there an interesting species whose generating function gives the zigzag numbers?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let's say a **[species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species)** is a functor

$$F: \mathrm{FinSet}_0 \to \mathrm{FinSet}_0$$

from the groupoid of finite sets and bijections to itself.  Let $F(n)$ be its value on your favorite $n$-element set; then its **generating function** is the formal power series

$$ |F|(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{|F(n)| z^n}{n!} $$

where the absolute value denotes cardinality.

In plain English: $F$ is a way of putting structures on finite sets, and the generating function is a power series whose $n$th coefficient is the number of ways of putting this structure on an $n$-element set, divided by $n!$.

Is there an interesting species whose generating function is $\sec z + \tan z$?

There's an answer that comes frustratingly close to being good.  We have

$$  \sec z + \tan z = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{A_n z^n}{n!} $$

where $A_n$ is the $n$th **[Euler zigzag number](https://oeis.org/A000111)**.  This is the number of permutations $\sigma$ of the set $\{1, \dots, n\}$ that are **[alternating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation)**, by which I mean that

$$ \sigma(1) < \sigma(2) > \sigma(3) < \sigma(4) > \cdots $$

For example, here is a picture that shows $A_4 = 5$, drawn by [Robert M. Dickau](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110063213/http://mathforum.org/advanced/robertd/zigzag.html):

[image: The fourth Euler zigzag number]

This seems nice and combinatorial.  However, to define an alternating permutation of a finite set, we need to equip it with a total ordering.  There is a species that assigns to any finite set its collection of total orderings *together with* alternating permutations... but for an $n$-element set, there are $A_{n}$ times $n!$ of these, so the generating function of this species is

$$  \sum_{n = 0}^\infty A_{n} z^{n}, $$

not what I want.

I believe we could fix this by creating a species $F$ that assigns to each finite set the collection of *isomorphism classes* of total orderings and alternating permutations, where two are considered isomorphic if they differ by the action of a permutation.  However, the resulting species, if indeed it's well-defined, will be 'uninteresting' in that now

$$F: \mathrm{FinSet}_0 \to \mathrm{FinSet}_0$$

maps every permutation of a finite set to an identity morphism.

Richard Stanley has many other interpretations of the Euler zigzag numbers in [A survey of alternating permutations](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4240).  However, I believe they all suffer from the same problem: they count structures on *totally ordered* finite sets.  In this situation we expect to get the [ordinary generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_function)

$$  \sum_{n = 0}^\infty A_{n} z^{n} $$

rather than the [exponential generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function)

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{A_n z^n}{n!} $$

If this is inevitable, I'd like to know why the function $\sec z + \tan z$ comes so close to being the generating function of an interesting species, yet fails!  Could we get it using a species valued in some other groupoid, like the groupoid of finite-dimensional vector spaces?  Or maybe some other trick?

Comment: You want $F(6)$ to be an $S_6$-set of order $A_6=61$, which does not divide $|S_6|=720$, so the action cannot be transitive.  Maybe $F(6)$ could split as a single fixed point plus an orbit of size $60$, which would have a stabiliser of order $12$.  There are some obvious dihedral groups of order $12$ in $S_6$ that could be the stabilisers.  Perhaps this kind of analysis might be helpful?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that way of attacking the problem!

Comment: Wouldn't the representation corresponding to the zig-zag shape $\tau_n$ described in Section 3.6 of Stanley's survey qualify?  Of course, that's not a permutation representation, but at least you get a functor into finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: I don't really understand that passage of Stanley.  If he gives a nontrivial functor from the groupoid of finite sets to the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces such that any $n$-element set gets mapped to a vector space of dimension $A_n$, I will be happy.  ("Trivial" here means that all automorphisms get sent to identity morphisms.)

Comment: Let $n=3$, then $\tau_n$ is a square Ferrers diagram with the top-left cell missing. Let $U=\{a,b,c\}$. The functor takes $U$ to the Specht module of polytabloids of shape $\tau_n$.  A basis is for example $\begin{array}{cc} & a\\ b & c\end{array}-\begin{array}{cc} & c\\ a & b\end{array}$ and the same with $b$ and $c$ interchanged. The symmetric group $\mathfrak S_{a,b,c}$ acts on this module, in particular, the transposition $(b,c)$ switches the two basis elements.

Comment: Actually, a follow-up question to my construction above (reproduced much nicer by Ira below): is this an "interesting" way of looking at $A_n$?  Having a $\mathfrak S_n$ module is of course much weaker than having a permutation representation.  Here's a list of the first few characters of the module: $s[1, 1]\\
 s[2, 1]\\
 s[2, 1, 1] + s[2, 2]\\
 s[2, 2, 1] + s[3, 1, 1] + s[3, 2]\\
 s[2, 2, 1, 1] + s[2, 2, 2] + s[3, 1, 1, 1] + 2s[3, 2, 1] + s[3, 3]\\
 s[2, 2, 2, 1] + 2s[3, 2, 1, 1] + 2s[3, 2, 2] + 2s[3, 3, 1] + s[4, 1, 1, 1] + 2s[4, 2, 1] + s[4, 3]$

Answer (score 8):

Here's a more self-contained description of this module.
For simplicity, I'll consider only the case $n=2m$.
Consider the vector space $V$ spanned by the set $P$ of ordered partitions of $[2m]$  into $m$ blocks of size two. The symmetric group $S_{2m}$ acts naturally on $V$.
Now let $T$ be the set of ordered partitions of $[2m]$ with $m-2$ blocks of size two and one block of size 4, and for $t\in T$, let $\alpha(t)$ be the sum in $V$ of all the elements of $P$ from which $t$ can be obtained by merging two adjacent blocks. Then the quotient of $V$ by the $S_n$-module spanned by the $\alpha(t)$ is the desired $S_{2m}$-module, with dimension $A_{2m}$.

For example, with $n=4$, there are 6 ordered partitions:

12 | 34,  13 | 24,  14 | 23,  34 | 12,  24 | 13,  and 23 | 14.

There is only one element $t\in T$, and $\alpha(t)$ is the sum of all six ordered partitions in $P$, so the quotient module has dimension $5=A_4$.

Instead of ordered partitions of $[2m]$ we could have used any $2m$-element set, and it is clear that the construction is functorial.